# Paste to a new string var, but collapsed by new line for Lavaan

Tags: r, newline

I have a large SEM an am using Lavaan package.
As it is large, I use loops to generate the equations. It seems, however, that it is necessary for the equations to be input as a string, where each equation is a new line. eg:

```
model <- '
    F1_all =~ target 
    F2_all =~ target 
    F3_all =~ target
'
```

Simply separating by a space results in an error: 
"Error in ~targetF3_all = ~target : object 'targetF3_all' not found"

My issue is that I need to be able to CREATE a string by pasting and collapsing by newline, so cat() isn't an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, but see if my solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collapse=` argument in `paste`:

```
model = paste(c('F1_all =~ target', 'F2_all =~ target', 'F3_all =~ target'), 
              collapse = '\n')
# [1] "F1_all =~ target\nF2_all =~ target\nF3_all =~ target"
```